# Reversing y-axis in an individual ggplot facet

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting a range of different data measured on the same individuals next to each other in facets. For some types of data a positive value is "good" and for some a negative value is "good". The latter types of variables are usually plotted with flipped y-axes. Is it possible to modify axis directions in individual facets with ggplot?

```
dat <- data.frame(type = rep(c('A', 'B'), each = 10), x = 1:10, y = rnorm(20))

ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap( ~ type, scales = 'free_y')
```

[image]

For example, could I do the above plot with the y-axis for B reversed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if that's possible, so I would opt for a solution using the `grid.arrange` function from the **`gridExtra`** package.

```
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)

dat <- data.frame(type = rep(c('A', 'B'), each = 10), x = 1:10, y = rnorm(20),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

p_A <- ggplot(subset(dat, type == 'A'), aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap( ~ type, scales = 'free_y')+
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(-1,0,1))
p_B <- ggplot(subset(dat, type == 'B'), aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap( ~ type, scales = 'free_y')+
    scale_y_reverse(breaks = c(-1,0,1))

grid.arrange(p_A, p_B, nrow = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I had a feeling that this was the only real solution that didn't require massive amounts of coding. I'll accept it as it is probably the best solution available, but I had really hoped for something that generalized well to more complex faceting with `facet_grid`.

Answer (score 3):

This can now also be achieved using the `ggh4x` [package](https://teunbrand.github.io/ggh4x/articles/Facets.html) or the `facetscales` package (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51735481/ggplot2-change-axis-limits-for-each-individual-facet-panel) for `facetscales` approach):

```
library(ggh4x)

dat <- data.frame(type = rep(c('A', 'B'), each = 10), x = 1:10, y = rnorm(20))

scales <- list(
  scale_y_continuous(),
  scale_y_reverse()
  )

ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap( ~ type, scales = 'free_y') +
  facetted_pos_scales(y = scales)
```