# R, rotating one ggplot within facet_wrap?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I'm having a ggplot2 facet_wrap based upon on factor with two levels. To make them easier comparable, I would like to reverse the y-axis of one of them, e.g. by using scale_y_reverse. But I haven't found a way to apply it to only one of plots?[image] Is there an elegant way to do so?

Comment: See this may will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43915441/reversing-y-axis-in-an-individual-ggplot-facet

Comment: yes I feared the suggested answer would be the way to go, I had a similar thing in my mind ;-) thanks anyway