# ggplot2 + facet_: Reverse axes for some facets?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I've got three subplots I want to put together into one plot, and faceting would be a natural way to do it. However, one of these subplots would be easier/more natural to read with a reversed x-axis (whereas I'd like to leave the others alone). Is there a way to accomplish this using facet_grid() or facet_wrap()?

The other alternative I've considered is grid.arrange(), and the chief problem I've run into there is getting it to align the subplots based on plot area (inside the axes), rather than based on the edges of the images. (My axis titles and labels are not the same size, so the default behavior is fairly ugly.)

**Edited to add a MWE** with some data for context. Here, since larger is "better" for the beta and R-squared subplots, it would be more natural to reverse the axis for the p subplot. (In this case it would probably also be better to add the log transform to that scale, but my real problem doesn't need to get that fancy.)

```
df <- data.frame(z=c(rep("R-squared",15),rep("p",15),rep("beta",15)),
                 x=c(runif(15),exp(-runif(15,1,10)),rnorm(15,1,0.5)),
                 y=rep(letters[1:15],3))
plot <- ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y)) + facet_grid(.~z, scales="free_x", switch="x")
```

Comment: It's much easier to help if you provide some sort of minimal [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with some sample data/code that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: New answers to this quesion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43915441/reversing-y-axis-in-an-individual-ggplot-facet/65570612#65570612 and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51735481/ggplot2-change-axis-limits-for-each-individual-facet-panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution using [patchwork](https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(z=c(rep("R-squared",15),rep("p",15),rep("beta",15)),
                 x=c(runif(15),exp(-runif(15,1,10)),rnorm(15,1,0.5)),
                 y=rep(letters[1:15],3))

p1 <- ggplot(filter(df, z == "beta"), aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() 

p2 <- ggplot(filter(df, z == "p"), aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_reverse() +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y  = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank())

p3 <- ggplot(filter(df, z == "R-squared"), aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y  = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank())

#devtools::install_github("thomasp85/patchwork")
library(patchwork)
p1 + p2 + p3
```

[image: patchwork_plot]

Comment: It took some trial and error to install the package (I hadn't realized I needed to install from a fresh session of R), but once I got it working, it did exactly what I wanted. This is gorgeous.

Comment: Great! Glad to help!